# Navigating to another Screen when a button is tapped in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm quite new to React Native, I want to open another screen when a button is tapped, the screen that I want to show is already created. I have used `TouchableOpacity` as my button and used navigation on "`onPress`" prop. My app is already using Stack navigator and Tab navigator so I have installed those packages.

I have tried but I'm getting an error "`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')`"

Please help.

In the screen where I'm showing the button:

```
const myWebview = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.button}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NewListingScreen")}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#ffffff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
            My Button Title
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
};
```

On my Tab Navigator (The screen works fine):

```
<Tab.Screen
        name={routes.newListingScreen}
        component={NewListingScreen}
        options={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabBarButton: () => (
            <NewListingButton
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate(routes.newListingScreen);
                dispatch({
                  type: "SET_NEW_LISTING_SCREEN",
                  newListingScreen: true,
                });
              }}
            />
          ),
          tabBarVisible: !user,
        })}
      />
```

[image]

When I use `const navigation = useNavigation();`

I get this error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first guess is that the `navigation` object itself is `undefined` here. Navigation prop is [only available](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/) on screens. -

```
const myWebview = ({ navigation }) => {
```

Using `hooks` is a better alternative to passing navigation objects to child components.

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function NotificationsScreen() {
const navigation = useNavigation(); 
return(
 ...
  <TouchableOpacity
     style={styles.button}
     onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewListingScreen')}
  >
 ...
);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had tried that option before, but it gives me another error (I have edited my question to show the error)

Comment: @Amos - In your route definition, is the string `NewListingScreen` correctly mapped to a screen? What is the value of `routes.newListingScreen`?

Comment: in my routes.js I have `newListingScreen: "New Listing"`

Comment: Then try - `navigation.navigate('New Listing')`