# How to use props in React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I know that my issue can be solved by using props, but I don't know what exactly should I do. I'm making a navigation between screens and my buttons are individual components, I have no problem when I just copying code of the buttons and paste it to the main screen, but I want to have them separetely, however in such a case - navigation isn't working. I want to navigate you to the "About" screen when you click the button.

### Home Screen

```js
import { View, Text, ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

const image = { uri: "https://i.ibb.co/JtnTCS1/BG.png" };

// State
import { useState } from "react";

// Fonts
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

// Components
import PlayButton from "../components/PlayButton";
import AboutButton from "../components/AboutButton";
import SettingsButton from "../components/SettingsButton";

// Navigation
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

// font
import { FONTFAMILY } from "../theme";

// On Press

const Home = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Musketeer: require("../assets/fonts/Pixel-Musketeer.otf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return (
    <View className="bg-mainRed flex-1 justify-center items-center flex-col">
      <ImageBackground
        source={image}
        resizeMode="cover"
        className="flex-1 justify-center w-screen"
      >
        <View className="mb-16">
          <Text
            style={FONTFAMILY.musketeer}
            className="text-brightGreen text-notsobig text-center mb-16"
          >
            KING'S DUNGEON
          </Text>
          <View className="flex flex-col">
            <PlayButton></PlayButton>
            <AboutButton></AboutButton>
            <SettingsButton></SettingsButton>
          </View>
          <Text
            style={FONTFAMILY.musketeer}
            className="text-brightGreen text-small mt-10 text-center"
          >
            Made By Ruslan Makhamtov
          </Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ForText: {
    fontSize: "75px",
  },
});

export default Home;
```

### About Screen

```js
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

// font
import { FONTFAMILY } from "../theme";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";

const About = () => {
  const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    Musketeer: require("../assets/fonts/Pixel-Musketeer.otf"),
  });

  if (!fontsLoaded) return null;

  return (
    <View className="bg-mainRed flex-1">
      <Text>About</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default About;
```

### About Button

```js
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import React from "react";

// font
import { FONTFAMILY } from "../theme";

// OnPress

const PlayButton = ({ navigation }) => {
  const OnPress = () => navigation.navigate("About");
  return (
    <View className="mt-6" onPress={OnPress}>
      <TouchableOpacity className="flex justify-center items-center">
        <View className="bg-darkGreen border-solid border-4 border-darkGreen rounded w-9/12">
          <View className="bg-darkGreen border-solid border-4 border-green rounded justify-center items-center h-16">
            <Text
              style={FONTFAMILY.musketeer}
              className="text-greenText text-middleSize"
            >
              About
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default PlayButton;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navigating to another Screen when a button is tapped in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72183286/navigating-to-another-screen-when-a-button-is-tapped-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

If `HomeScreen` is a screen defined inside a navigator, then the `navigation` object will be passed to it as props. You can then pass it down to its children.

```js
const Home = ({navigation}) => {

    ...
    
    <AboutButton navigation={navigation} />
}
```

It might make sense here to encapsulate the navigation logic inside the button component itself in order to prevent changing it by other components. In this case you could use the `useNavigation` hook. No props involved here.

```js
function AboutButton() {
    const navigation = useNavigation()

    ...
}
```